# SAML2 SSO Authentication Issue - HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, sustainsys-saml2

I'm encountering a problem with SAML2 Single Sign-On (SSO) authentication in my ASP.NET application. The application is set up to load the **Home/Index** page on startup. If the user is not authenticated, it redirects to the SAML2 SSO login page. After a successful login, it should redirect to the **Member/Home** page. However, **I'm facing an issue where I receive an "HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized" error after successful login.** I am using **Sustainsys.SAML2.Owin** And the SP is salesforce.

I've also included the relevant parts of my Startup.cs, MemberController, and HomeController code.

Following is Startup.cs.

```
public class Startup { public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {

//JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = "Saml2",
    CookieManager = new Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.SystemWebChunkingCookieManager(),
    SlidingExpiration = true,
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sessionTime"].ToString()))
});

    app.UseSaml2Authentication(CreateSaml2Options());
}

private Saml2AuthenticationOptions CreateSaml2Options()
{
    var saml2Options = new Saml2AuthenticationOptions(false)
    {
        SPOptions = new SPOptions
        {
            EntityId = new EntityId(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EntityId"].ToString()),
            ReturnUrl = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReturnUrl"].ToString()),
        },
    };

    saml2Options.IdentityProviders.Add(
        new IdentityProvider(
            new EntityId(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IssuerUrl"].ToString()),
            saml2Options.SPOptions)
        {
            LoadMetadata = true,
            SingleSignOnServiceUrl = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SingleSignOnServiceUrl"].ToString()),
            MetadataLocation = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MetadataLocation"].ToString(),
            AllowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse = true,
        });

    saml2Options.AuthenticationType = "Saml2";

    return saml2Options;
}
}
```

**HomeController code**

```
public class HomeController : Controller 
{
     public ActionResult Index()
 { 
    bool isSAML = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnableSamlLogin"].ToString()); 
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Home", "Member");
}
else
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(isSAML.ToString()))
    {
        if (isSAML)
        {

            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                //RedirectUri = "Member/Home"
                RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReturnUrl"].ToString()
            }, "Saml2");

            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
return View();
}
```

**MemberController Code**

```
[Authorize] public class MemberController : Controller { // GET: Member public ActionResult Index() 
{    return View();
}
   
public ActionResult Home()
{
    return View();
}
}
```

I expected that after a successful SAML SSO login, the application would redirect the user to the Member/Home page, and the user would be authenticated and authorized to access that page.

Comment: I gotta know - why are you still using SAML?

Comment: It is client requirement. Client is using Salesforce SAML based SSO.

Comment: @Dai do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The Owin model is not very elegant when there is an error during the authentication. If the Saml2 response processing fails, the redirect is still done, but with an added query string parameter `error=access_denied`. Is that query string added? If it is, then enabling logs should give you a detailed error message.

Comment: No it does not add error=access_denied in the query string. idP is functioning fine. I think the issue is that I am not able to set the User Context in order to access the Secured URLS. e.g. [Authorize] urls.

Answer (score 0):

If you redirecting right after setting up a cookie is not a good thing, you will lose the session. Set the cookie/session and have a setTimeout to redirect the page but in the client side. I code if ruby so I didn't check your code but the behavior should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. Since I was using FormAuthentication, that's why I has to set `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginInd)` after being redirected from **ACS**.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Home()
{
    string samlResponse =.Params["SAMLResponse"];
    byte[] samlBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(samlResponse);
    string samlXml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(samlBytes);
    System.Xml.Linq.XDocument samlDocument = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(samlXml);

    XNamespace saml2Assertion = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion";

    loginInd = samlDocument.Descendants(saml2Assertion + "Attribute")
        .Where(attr => (string)attr.Attribute("Name") == "username")
        .Select(attr => attr.Element(saml2Assertion + "AttributeValue")?.Value);

    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginInd)

    return RedirectToAction("Secure", "Member", new { area = "" });
}


[Authorize]
public ActionResult Home()
{
}
```

Comment: This looks like you are parsing the Saml response yourself, without signature checks or other validation. To me this looks like a huge security problem.

Comment: Exactly this should be done by the SAML. But I don't know how.

Comment: Use the `AcsCommandResultCreated` callback to get the principal and call `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginInd)`